# the function does not update the parameter C

Tags: c, function, parameters

i have this function that extract the first name and the gendre form a file combined and then seperate them

for example the function extract "Aaliyah,F" and the separate them as `prenom = Aaliyah`  and `genre = F`

the problem is that the function does not update the `genre` value and still at `NULL`

so for this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int AleaNombre(int min, int max) {

    return (rand() % (max - min + 1)) + min;

}

void recuperer_prenom(char genre , char prenom[20] ) {
    FILE* f2 = fopen("C:\\Users\\PC PRO DZ\\Desktop\\Projects\\C\\TP essai\\prenom.txt", "r");
    fseek(f2, 0, SEEK_END);
    int length = ftell(f2);
    fseek(f2, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char line1[length + 1];
    fgets(line1, length + 1, f2);
    int i = AleaNombre(1, 100);
    int cpt = 0;
    char* tok = strtok(line1, " ; ");
    cpt++;
    while (cpt != i) {
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ; ");
        cpt++;
    }
    //separer le prenom et le genre tel que prenom,genre et le genre est le dernier caractere en utilisant strtok
    char* tok2 = strtok(tok, ",");
    strcpy(prenom, tok2);
    tok2 = strtok(NULL, ",");
    genre = tok2[0];
    printf("%s %c", prenom, genre); // the result is for example: "Aaliyah F"
    rewind(f2);//                                                   ^      ^
    fclose(f2);//                                               |prenom| |genre|
} 
int main () {
    srand (time(NULL));
    char prenom[20];
    char genre;
    recuperer_prenom(genre, prenom);
    printf ("%s %c", prenom, genre);// however the result here is "Aaliyah"
    return 0;
}
```

i tried changing the way that the `prenom` and `genre` are separated and change the type of `genre` from `char` to a sting but didn'f fixe it

Comment: Arguments are passed by value in C. Every text on the C language, even bad ones, cover this. `genre = ...` means *nothing* to the caller of `recuperer_prenom`

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between passing a function argument [by value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_value.htm) and [by reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm)?

Comment: To go along with arguments being passed by value, parameters declared as having array types are automatically adjusted to pointer types, so `recuperer_prenom`'s `char prenom[20]` parameter is really `char *prenom`. In most expressions, arrays are converted to a pointer to its initial element, so in that `recuperer_prenom(genre, prenom);` function call from `main`, `main`'s `prenom` array is converted to a pointer, and that pointer is passed by value to the `recuperer_prenom` function's `char *prenom` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the random part and created a struct to store your fields:
You should pass by reference as said in comment

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 256

typedef struct data {
    char prenom[20];
    char genre;
} data;

void recuperer_prenom(data *d) {
    FILE* f2 = fopen("prenom.txt", "r");
    char line1[MAXLINE];
    fgets(line1, MAXLINE, f2);
    char* tok = strtok(line1, " ; ");
    //separer le prenom et le genre tel que prenom,genre et le genre est le dernier caractere en utilisan>
    char* tok2 = strtok(tok, ",");
    strcpy(d->prenom, tok2); 
    tok2 = strtok(NULL, ",");
    d->genre = tok2[0]; 
    printf("%s %c\n", d->prenom, d->genre); // the result is for example: "Aaliyah F"
    fclose(f2);//                                               |prenom| |genre|
}   
int main () {
    data d; 
    recuperer_prenom(&d);
    printf ("%s %c\n", d.prenom, d.genre);// however the result here is "Aaliyah"
    return 0;
}
```